# Developing SharePoint working flow app using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create Workflow app for SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio 2015. But I gives compile time error

***"Workflow Manager Tools need to be installed to build this project"***

I Have installed all Workflow Manager Tools and office tools for vs2015.

Anyone came across similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting VS/computer after installation?

Check that Office Developer Tools is installed in VS -> Tools -> Extensions and updates. Also run VS as Administrator after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Updating VS 2015 from extensions and updates solved my problem